# How do I call/schedule a function after an action is completed?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I am working on a multiplayer domino game where a device acts as a host and makes the decisions for the rest of the players.  So far, it works great when everyone has a good connection, but once you introduce some latency, all things go to heck.  One problem I'm having is that I need to move some sprites around on command.  When everyone has played, the host device will send a message out that tells the remote players who won the hand.  After that message is sent, the winner can make the next move.

I move the dominoes to the right using:

```
void HelloWorld::onChatReceived(AppWarp::chat chatevent)
{
        if (chatprefix.compare("_determinewinner_")==0)
        {
            //chatstring in this case is the playerID who won the hand
            MultiPlayerdetermineTrickWinner(atoi(chatstring.c_str()));
        }
}

void HelloWorld::MultiPlayerdetermineTrickWinner(int winningplayer)
{
...
for (int i = 0; i <marray_table->count(); ++i)
{
            Domino *marray_table_tile = (Domino *)(marray_table->objectAtIndex(i));
            CCMoveTo *translate = CCMoveTo::create(0.1f,ccp(pos_x,pos_y));
            CCRotateBy *rotleft=CCRotateBy::create(0.1f, 90*int_rotate);
            marray_table_tile->runAction(CCSequence::create(translate,rotleft,NULL));
}
...
}
```

When the players selects a tile, I call

```
    CCMoveTo *translate = CCMoveTo::create(0.1f,ccp(pos_x,pos_y));
    selectedtile->runAction(CCSequence::create(translate,NULL));
    marray_table->addObject(selectedtile);
```

The problem I have is, that there are times when the latency is so bad, that the runaction never completes and the tiles don't actually make it to their final position.  For instance, if the host player won the hand and makes their move before the other players received the "determinewinner" message.  So short of having all the players tell the host when it can move on, how do I schedule a function to occur only after all actions have been completed?